# Is there a way to restrict dashboard view in AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-ssm

As a developer, I want to see if I can restrict the view of AWS Dashboards based on your role and team. As of now, all dashboard are visible and accessible for all users who share same AWS account.

I looked at the options AWS currently have on their platform under *Actions*, and it seems like you can share the dashboard, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I want the user to go to *AWS Systems Manager>Dashboard by CloudWatch* and see the dashboard they are eligible to see. For example, if you are from group A, you will see Tomato dashboard, and if you are from group B, you will see Pineapple dashboard.

Is there a way to do that? Or it's not something that AWS is supporting as of now?

If there's no direct way to achieve this within CloudWatch Dashboard service, what other routes you suggest?

Comment: Use IAM & the policies relating to dashboard to prevent access to get specific dashboards depending on user / role - view: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/dashboard-permissions-update.html

Comment: That doesn't seem to give me control over a specific dashboard

Comment: You restrict it via the ARN of the dashboard.